# How can I compare 2 list and remove the a string from 1 list that contain a substring from other list? Python

Tags: python, compare

is there anyway I can remove a specific string if other list contain a substring of it? For example:
list x contain the substring, since y[0] have 'hi'(which contain in list x) inside the word, I would like to remove it.

```
x=["yo",'sup','hi']

y= ['hi-test','test2','test3']
```

This is what I have try, but I think my concept are wrong.

```
x=["yo",'sup','hi']
y= ['hi-test','test2','test3']
list1=[]
for namex in x:
    for namey in y:
        if namex in namey:
            break
        else:
            list1.append(namey)

print(list1)
```

I would like to get a list with 'test2' and 'test3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one-line list comprehension:

```
list1 = [y_word for y_word in y 
              if not any(x_word in y_word for x_word in x)]
```

In common terms:

for each phrase in `y`, check to see whether *any* word in `x` is in that phrase.  If not, then add that phrase to our new `list1`.

Output:

```
['test2', 'test3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. It iterates through `x` then checks if any string in x is a substring of any string in `y`.

```
x=["yo",'sup','hi']
y= ['hi-test','test2','test3']
for count,letters in enumerate(x):
    for letters2 in y:
        if letters in letters2:x.pop(count)
print(x)
```

**output**

```
['yo', 'sup']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong this is what you expect:

```
x=["yo",'sup','hi']
y= ['hi','test2','test3']
list1=[]
for namex in x:
    for namey in y:
        if namex in namey:
            del(y[0])
print(list1.append(y))
```